# Rundeck Job Not Stopping Execution Properly

Tags: rundeck

I have a Rundeck job that performs a data archival task. The job executes successfully, but when I try to kill the job from the Rundeck UI, it seems to keep inserting records until all the data is moved to the archive table.

Note I am using php script to move the DB records into archive table.

here are the rundeck job logs:

```
query, job_273::moveRecords, 1.7757458686829, DANGER
12:00:32            **** job_273::moveRecords time taken 1.8048849105835 sec, offset: 6000 
12:00:32            
12:00:32            **** Job 273:: Success, data archived successfully!!
12:00:32            
12:00:35            query, job_273::moveRecords, 1.5157968997955, DANGER
12:00:35            **** job_273::moveRecords time taken 1.5820739269257 sec, offset: 7000 
12:00:35            
12:00:35            **** Job 273:: Success, data archived successfully!!
12:00:35            
12:00:39            query, job_273::moveRecords, 1.6569089889526, DANGER
12:00:39            **** job_273::moveRecords time taken 1.689309835434 sec, offset: 8000 
12:00:39            
12:00:39            **** Job 273:: Success, data archived successfully!!


**** Job 290:: Success, data archived successfully!!

12:00:39            
12:00:43            Result: 2147483647
12:00:43            Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Result code was 2147483647
12:00:43            java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
12:00:43                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:121)
12:00:43                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
12:00:43                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135)
12:00:43                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1158)
12:00:43                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
12:00:43                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
12:00:43                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
12:00:43            Cancellation while running step [1]
12:00:43            Execution failed: 4503990 in project BIM_QA: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Interrupted: Cancellation while running step [1]}, flow control: Continue, status: failed]
```

Despite this, the job continues until completion.

Here are some details:

Rundeck version: [2.10.7-1]

Has anyone encountered a similar problem, and what steps can I take to ensure that killing the job stops the execution immediately?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's a common behavior reported [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1038) (and marked for enhancement). You can see multiple strategies in the original thread like:

1. Delegate the behavior on the script [directly](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1038#issuecomment-248058644).
2. Use a Python script to [execute](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1038#issuecomment-389164807).
3. [Use](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1038#issuecomment-543844446) an [Error handler](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-workflows.html#error-handlers) in your workflow.

[Here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1038#issuecomment-461290416) a good explanation of this based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124127/kill-all-descendant-processes) answer.